# MSBuild error MSB3107

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

I get the following error on an MSBuild: MSB3107

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets (1001): The specified project reference metadata for the reference "....\Contracts\Contracts.csproj" is missing or has an invalid value: Project

Since I didn't found many information on the internet on MSB3107 I'll figured I'll post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this, by removing all the references to Contracts.csproj and put them back with program reference. This was an easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and it ended up being that the scproj's `ToolsVersion` (attribute on the root `Project` element) was set to 3.5. Changing it to 4.0 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Find and remove this line :

*< Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />*

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when converting a Xamarin Studio solution to a Visual Studio 2017 for Mac solution.

**/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5,5): 
Error MSB3107: The specified project reference metadata for the reference "{myproject}.csproj" is missing or has an invalid value: Project (MSB3107) ({myproject})**

I ended up creating a brand new solution file (sln) then new skeleton csproj files that were native iOS libraries. I copied the classes, and manually added the references again. The fundamental difference appears to be to remove these XML entries in the .csproj file in the first PropertyGroup section under the Project tag.

```
<TargetFrameworkIdentifier>Xamarin.iOS</TargetFrameworkIdentifier>
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v1.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
<ProductVersion>8.0.30703</ProductVersion>
<SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
<ReleaseVersion>4.0</ReleaseVersion>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen due to a project reference with a bad project GUID. If a merge from a version control system goes bad, the referenced ID can be corrupted. Editing the .csproj file to get rid of the bad reference, then adding a fresh reference again from Visual Studio can fix this type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred in our solution after removing a redundant curly brace in a project's GUID. After deleting the .vs folder (or running a `git clean -fdx`) and restarting VisualStudio the error did not show up any longer.